# mac m1 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Tags: java, macos, apple-m1

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0x000000010e6cb868, pid=4484, tid=0x0000000000002403
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_191-b12) (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
```

problem: # Problematic frame:
# j  com.sun.tools.javac.comp.ConstFold.fold2(ILcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;+877
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f84eb009000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=9219, stack(0x000000030485b000,0x000000030495b000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 8 (SIGFPE), si_code: 5 (FPE_FLTINV), si_addr: 0x000000010e6cb868

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000001, RBX=0x000000000000006c, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00000003049581f0, RBP=0x0000000304958238, RSI=0x0000000304958190, RDI=0x00000007c0011570
R8 =0x00000007777abf28, R9 =0x00000007777abf08, R10=0x000000010d108120, R11=0x000000010f1071c0
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000012c1db8c0, R14=0x0000000304958270, R15=0x00007f84eb009000
RIP=0x000000010e6cb868, EFLAGS=0x0000000000000a83, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x0000000000000000

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000003049581f0)
0x00000003049581f0:   000000077506ece0 00000003049581f8
0x0000000304958200:   000000012c1db8bd 0000000304958270
0x0000000304958210:   000000012c1dc5c0 000000012cb95ea8
0x0000000304958220:   000000012c1dc150 0000000000000000
0x0000000304958230:   0000000304958280 000000077507da30
0x0000000304958240:   000000010feee024 00000006c1034b10
0x0000000304958250:   00000006c1028340 00000007777abf28
0x0000000304958260:   00000007777abf08 000000070000006c
0x0000000304958270:   000000077507fae0 000000010feee024
0x0000000304958280:   00000006c19afb80 000000010ea03894
0x0000000304958290:   00000007f805b996 000000077507da30
0x00000003049582a0:   00000007756f8658 0000000700000002
0x00000003049582b0:   000000077507fd90 00000007777abdd0
0x00000003049582c0:   000000077506ece0 00000007777a73b8
0x00000003049582d0:   00000007759d7228 0000000110346fb4
0x00000003049582e0:   000000077add8f08 0000000000000000
0x00000003049582f0:   00000007777abd40 00000007759d7228
0x0000000304958300:   00000000eea0faba 000000010fe7f374
0x0000000304958310:   000000000000000c 000000010fe7d65c
0x0000000304958320:   0000000000000000 00000007777abd40
0x0000000304958330:   00000007777abdf0 00000007777abd40
0x0000000304958340:   00000007777abd40 0000000000000030
0x0000000304958350:   00000007777abdf0 000000077507da30
0x0000000304958360:   0000000000000001 000000010e8134a4
0x0000000304958370:   00000000eeadf0cb 000000077507d5d0
0x0000000304958380:   00000007756f8748 000000077507da30
0x0000000304958390:   00000007756f8838 00000007777abf08
0x00000003049583a0:   00007f84eb009000 00007f84eb009000
0x00000003049583b0:   000000077507d5d0 00000007756f8748
0x00000003049583c0:   00000007777abf08 00000007777abf28
0x00000003049583d0:   00000000634e5337 00007f84eb009000
0x00000003049583e0:   00000007777abe88 000000011a46f000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000010e6cb868)
0x000000010e6cb848:   c8 8b 04 24 48 83 c4 08 81 f8 00 00 00 80 0f 85
0x000000010e6cb858:   0b 00 00 00 33 d2 83 f9 ff 0f 84 03 00 00 00 99
0x000000010e6cb868:   f7 f9 41 0f b6 5d 01 49 ff c5 49 ba 20 81 10 0d
0x000000010e6cb878:   01 00 00 00 41 ff 24 da 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000000000006c is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00000003049581f0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f84eb009000
RBP=0x0000000304958238 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f84eb009000
RSI=0x0000000304958190 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f84eb009000
RDI=0x00000007c0011570 is pointing into metadata
R8 =0x00000007777abf28 is an oop
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$JCPrimitiveType$1 
 - klass: 'com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type$JCPrimitiveType$1'
R9 =0x00000007777abf08 is an oop
com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$JCPrimitiveType$1 
 - klass: 'com/sun/tools/javac/code/Type$JCPrimitiveType$1'
R10=0x000000010d108120: _ZN19TemplateInterpreter13_active_tableE+0x2000 in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_191.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib at 0x000000010c800000
R11=0x000000010f1071c0 is at entry_point+32 in (nmethod*)0x000000010f107050
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000012c1db8c0 is pointing into metadata
R14=0x0000000304958270 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f84eb009000
R15=0x00007f84eb009000 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000030485b000,0x000000030495b000],  sp=0x00000003049581f0,  free space=1012k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
j  com.sun.tools.javac.comp.ConstFold.fold2(ILcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;+877
J 6941 C1 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBinary(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCBinary;)V (301 bytes) @ 0x000000010feee024 [0x000000010feec100+0x1f24]
J 7646 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBinary.accept(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$Visitor;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x000000010f6abf24 [0x000000010f6abee0+0x44]
J 8325 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitVarDef(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCVariableDecl;)V (406 bytes) @ 0x000000010f61e620 [0x000000010f61d400+0x1220]
J 4996 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$Visitor;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x000000010f5db2a4 [0x000000010f5db260+0x44]
J 8612 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBlock(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCBlock;)V (363 bytes) @ 0x00000001103c7e54 [0x00000001103c7ae0+0x374]
J 5934 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$Visitor;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x000000010ea79f64 [0x000000010ea79f20+0x44]
J 7562 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Env;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type; (11 bytes) @ 0x000000010ecf3218 [0x000000010ecf3180+0x98]
j  com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitTry(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCTry;)V+246
J 7664 C1 com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCTry.accept(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$Visitor;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x000000010f6c0fcc [0x000000010f6c0ec0+0x10c]
J 8612 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBlock(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCBlock;)V (363 bytes) @ 0x00000001103c7e54 [0x00000001103c7ae0+0x374]
J 5934 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$Visitor;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x000000010ea79f64 [0x000000010ea79f20+0x44]
J 5637 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Env;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Attr$ResultInfo;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type; (148 bytes) @ 0x000000010f836ce0 [0x000000010f836c40+0xa0]
J 5891 C1 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitMethodDef(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCMethodDecl;)V (1198 bytes) @ 0x000000010f94a49c [0x000000010f943400+0x709c]
J 5728 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$Visitor;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x000000010edfeee4 [0x000000010edfeea0+0x44]
J 5637 C2 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Env;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Attr$ResultInfo;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type; (148 bytes) @ 0x000000010f836ce0 [0x000000010f836c40+0xa0]
J 7951 C1 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Env;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol$ClassSymbol;)V (726 bytes) @ 0x000000010f35c94c [0x000000010f358b60+0x3dec]
J 6935 C1 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol$ClassSymbol;)V (513 bytes) @ 0x000000010fecef24 [0x000000010fecc760+0x27c4]
J 8135 C1 com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/JCDiagnostic$DiagnosticPosition;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Symbol$ClassSymbol;)V (27 bytes) @ 0x00000001101293c4 [0x00000001101292e0+0xe4]
j  com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Env;)V+36
J 8282 C1 com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Env;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/comp/Env; (277 bytes) @ 0x000000010fee7c5c [0x000000010fee5b60+0x20fc]
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2()V+177
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/List;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/List;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)V+165
j  com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/Context;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/util/List;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/main/Main$Result;+1299
j  com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall()Lcom/sun/tools/javac/main/Main$Result;+59
j  com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call()Ljava/lang/Boolean;+1
j  org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/codehaus/plexus/compiler/CompilerConfiguration;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/codehaus/plexus/compiler/CompilerResult;+129
j  org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(Lorg/codehaus/plexus/compiler/CompilerConfiguration;)Lorg/codehaus/plexus/compiler/CompilerResult;+211
j  org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute()V+3204
j  org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.execute()V+20
j  org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution;)V+152
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ProjectIndex;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/DependencyContext;)V+215
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecution;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ProjectIndex;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/DependencyContext;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/PhaseRecorder;)V+6
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Ljava/util/List;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ProjectIndex;)V+60
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ReactorContext;Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/TaskSegment;)V+179
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ReactorContext;Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/TaskSegment;)V+7
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ReactorContext;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ProjectBuildList;Ljava/util/List;Lorg/apache/maven/lifecycle/internal/ReactorBuildStatus;)V+77
j  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;)V+348
j  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest;Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenSession;Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionResult;Lorg/eclipse/aether/DefaultRepositorySystemSession;)Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionResult;+425
j  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest;)Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionResult;+98
j  org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionRequest;)Lorg/apache/maven/execution/MavenExecutionResult;+2
j  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(Lorg/apache/maven/cli/CliRequest;)I+27
j  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(Lorg/apache/maven/cli/CliRequest;)I+66
j  org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main([Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/ClassWorld;)I+24
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2ef9fe]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4d6524]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4d6a58]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x347f4c]
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+56
j  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced([Ljava/lang/String;)V+45
j  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch([Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
j  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode([Ljava/lang/String;)I+101
j  org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+1
j  org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2ef9fe]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x3269a5]
V  [libjvm.dylib+0x31f731]
C  [java+0x38c6]  JavaMain+0x9c4
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x6950]  _pthread_start+0xe0
C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x247b]  thread_start+0xf
C  0x0000000000000000


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007f84aa32d000 JavaThread "JGit-WorkQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15367, stack(0x0000000305ed5000,0x0000000305fd5000)]
  0x00007f84aa98d000 JavaThread "process reaper" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=38247, stack(0x0000000305eaa000,0x0000000305ed2000)]
  0x00007f84ebacd000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=40351, stack(0x0000000305da7000,0x0000000305ea7000)]
  0x00007f84eb84f000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=41231, stack(0x0000000305ba1000,0x0000000305ca1000)]
  0x00007f84ea036800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=41475, stack(0x0000000305a9e000,0x0000000305b9e000)]
  0x00007f84ea82a000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=41987, stack(0x000000030599b000,0x0000000305a9b000)]
  0x00007f84ea81b800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=23299, stack(0x0000000305898000,0x0000000305998000)]
  0x00007f84eb82e800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=42755, stack(0x0000000305795000,0x0000000305895000)]
  0x00007f84eb815800 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=22599, stack(0x0000000305692000,0x0000000305792000)]
  0x00007f84ea035800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=43267, stack(0x000000030558f000,0x000000030568f000)]
  0x00007f84eb02b000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19227, stack(0x000000030537c000,0x000000030547c000)]
  0x00007f84ea02b000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19747, stack(0x0000000305279000,0x0000000305379000)]
=>0x00007f84eb009000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_Java, id=9219, stack(0x000000030485b000,0x000000030495b000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00007f84ea02a800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000305176000,0x0000000305276000] [id=14083]
  0x00007f84eb06e800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000305ca4000,0x0000000305da4000] [id=24603]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 272896K, used 224430K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x0000000787880000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 262144K, 81% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x0000000777bb1aa0,0x000000077ab00000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077b57a0a8,0x000000077b580000)
  to   space 28672K, 0% used [0x0000000785c80000,0x0000000785c80000,0x0000000787880000)
 ParOldGen       total 132096K, used 37244K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c8100000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 132096K, 28% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c245f020,0x00000006c8100000)
 Metaspace       used 31490K, capacity 32580K, committed 32768K, reserved 1079296K
  class space    used 3483K, capacity 3806K, committed 3840K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x000000011da6f000,0x000000011e270000] byte_map_base: 0x000000011a46f000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x000000010d0f9e00
 Begin Bits: [0x000000011e7c6000, 0x00000001227c6000)
 End Bits:   [0x00000001227c6000, 0x00000001267c6000)

Polling page: 0x00000001084d8000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=30069Kb max_used=30086Kb free=215690Kb
 bounds [0x000000010e6af000, 0x000000011043f000, 0x000000011d6af000]
 total_blobs=7493 nmethods=7063 adapters=344
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 17.013 Thread 0x00007f84ea82a000 8678       4       com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type$UndetVar::addBound (9 bytes)
Event: 17.014 Thread 0x00007f84ea82a000 nmethod 8678 0x00000001103d5150 code [0x00000001103d52a0, 0x00000001103d5348]
Event: 17.015 Thread 0x00007f84ea036800 8679       3       com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types::glb (58 bytes)
Event: 17.016 Thread 0x00007f84ea036800 nmethod 8679 0x0000000110420b10 code [0x0000000110420d00, 0x00000001104216b8]
Event: 17.021 Thread 0x00007f84ea82a000 8680 %     4       com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassWriter::writePool @ 18 (1051 bytes)
Event: 17.023 Thread 0x00007f84ea036800 8682       3       com.sun.tools.javac.comp.DeferredAttr$DeferredAttrContext::insideOverloadPhase (35 bytes)
Event: 17.024 Thread 0x00007f84ea036800 nmethod 8682 0x0000000110416a50 code [0x0000000110416be0, 0x0000000110416f48]
Event: 17.031 Thread 0x00007f84eb82e800 nmethod 8676 0x0000000110431610 code [0x0000000110431980, 0x0000000110433160]
Event: 17.031 Thread 0x00007f84eb82e800 8681       4       com.sun.tools.javac.util.ListBuffer$1::next (39 bytes)
Event: 17.032 Thread 0x00007f84eb82e800 nmethod 8681 0x000000011042e610 code [0x000000011042e760, 0x000000011042e838]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 2.640 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 76288K, used 74024K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x0000000774000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65536K, 100% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076eb00000,0x000000076eb00000)
  from space 10752K, 78% used [0x000000076eb00000,0x000000076f34a230,0x000000076f580000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000773580000,0x0000000773580000,0x0000000774000000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 0K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006cab00000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 15960K, capacity 16322K, committed 16640K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1907K, capacity 2010K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2.679 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=2 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 141824K, used 10750K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x0000000774000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131072K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x0000000772b00000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x0000000773580000,0x0000000773fffb58,0x0000000774000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000772b00000,0x0000000772b00000,0x0000000773580000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 869K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006cab00000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c00d94d0,0x00000006cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 15960K, capacity 16322K, committed 16640K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 1907K, capacity 2010K, committed 2048K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 4.791 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 141824K, used 141822K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x0000000774000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131072K, 100% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x0000000772b00000,0x0000000772b00000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x0000000773580000,0x0000000773fffb58,0x0000000774000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000772b00000,0x0000000772b00000,0x0000000773580000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 869K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006cab00000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 175104K, 0% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c00d94d0,0x00000006cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 17900K, capacity 18352K, committed 18688K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2052K, capacity 2219K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 4.850 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=3 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 141824K, used 10736K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x000000077c000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131072K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x0000000772b00000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x0000000772b00000,0x000000077357c010,0x0000000773580000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000077b580000,0x000000077b580000,0x000000077c000000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 17569K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006cab00000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 175104K, 10% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c11286d8,0x00000006cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 17900K, capacity 18352K, committed 18688K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2052K, capacity 2219K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 5.318 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 141824K, used 33411K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x000000077c000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 131072K, 17% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076c124e60,0x0000000772b00000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x0000000772b00000,0x000000077357c010,0x0000000773580000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000077b580000,0x000000077b580000,0x000000077c000000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 17569K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006cab00000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 175104K, 10% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c11286d8,0x00000006cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 20551K, capacity 21072K, committed 21248K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2337K, capacity 2527K, committed 2560K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 5.342 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=4 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 272896K, used 10720K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x000000077c000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 262144K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x000000077ab00000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x000000077b580000,0x000000077bff8040,0x000000077c000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077b580000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 19948K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006cab00000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 175104K, 11% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c137b328,0x00000006cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 20551K, capacity 21072K, committed 21248K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2337K, capacity 2527K, committed 2560K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 5.342 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=5 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 272896K, used 10720K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x000000077c000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 262144K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x000000077ab00000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x000000077b580000,0x000000077bff8040,0x000000077c000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077b580000)
 ParOldGen       total 175104K, used 19948K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006cab00000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 175104K, 11% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c137b328,0x00000006cab00000)
 Metaspace       used 20551K, capacity 21072K, committed 21248K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2337K, capacity 2527K, committed 2560K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 5.432 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=5 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 272896K, used 0K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x000000077c000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 262144K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x000000077ab00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000077b580000,0x000000077b580000,0x000000077c000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077b580000)
 ParOldGen       total 132096K, used 26302K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c8100000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 132096K, 19% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c19afb08,0x00000006c8100000)
 Metaspace       used 20551K, capacity 21072K, committed 21248K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 2337K, capacity 2527K, committed 2560K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 11.560 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=6 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 272896K, used 262144K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x000000077c000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 262144K, 100% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077ab00000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000077b580000,0x000000077b580000,0x000000077c000000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077b580000)
 ParOldGen       total 132096K, used 26302K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c8100000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 132096K, 19% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c19afb08,0x00000006c8100000)
 Metaspace       used 30715K, capacity 31812K, committed 32000K, reserved 1077248K
  class space    used 3451K, capacity 3742K, committed 3840K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 11.605 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=6 (full 1):
 PSYoungGen      total 272896K, used 10728K [0x000000076ab00000, 0x0000000787880000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 262144K, 0% used [0x000000076ab00000,0x000000076ab00000,0x000000077ab00000)
  from space 10752K, 99% used [0x000000077ab00000,0x000000077b57a0a8,0x000000077b580000)
  to   space 28672K, 0% used [0x0000000785c80000,0x0000000785c80000,0x0000000787880000)
 ParOldGen       total 132096K, used 37244K [0x00000006c0000000, 0x00000006c8100000, 0x000000076ab00000)
  object space 132096K, 28% used [0x00000006c0000000,0x00000006c245f020,0x00000006c8100000)
 Metaspace       used 30715K, capacity 31812K, committed 32000K, reserved 1077248K
  class space    used 3451K, capacity 3742K, committed 3840K, reserved 1048576K
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed the same issue by changing the JDK from the Oracle version to the Zulu one.

You can download the ARM-64 supported JDK 8 built by Zulu from the following link:
https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-8-lts&os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64788161/2906153