# Intellij error: Abnormal build process termination

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I spent a day trying to solve this but I would like to ask for assistance:

I keep getting this error:

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
/Users/gusiwanaga/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.2/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=/Users/gusiwanaga/Documents/Java/CodeGymTasks "-Dpreload.config.path=/Users/gusiwanaga/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/options" -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-5811705571438926815 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=DE -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2020.3 "-Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents" "-Didea.config.path=/Users/gusiwanaga/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3" "-Didea.plugins.path=/Users/gusiwanaga/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/plugins" -Djps.log.dir=/Users/gusiwanaga/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.9.1 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/gusiwanaga/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server/codegymtasks_d7c8260e/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/var/folders/gn/5kpsh7ds7w1b9nhkv87sph7r0000gn/T/kotlin-idea-7351053116812555786-is-running\" -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/netty-codec-4.1.52.Final.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-builder-support-3.6.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-resolver-util-1.3.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http-1.3.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.7.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jna-platform.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/httpclient-4.5.12.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic-1.3.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-model-builder-3.6.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/lz4-java-1.7.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/plexus-utils-3.2.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/intellij-deps-fastutil-8.4.1-4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/netty-buffer-4.1.52.Final.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-resolver-api-1.3.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.25.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.6.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-resolver-impl-1.3.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-artifact-3.6.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/commons-lang3-3.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-model-3.6.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/netty-transport-4.1.52.Final.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-resolver-provider-3.6.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/netty-common-4.1.52.Final.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file-1.3.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/resources_en.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/httpcore-4.4.13.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/maven-resolver-spi-1.3.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-model.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/qdox-2.0-M10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/asm-all-9.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/platform-api.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/forms-1.1-preview.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/protobuf-java-3.13.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension-1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/annotations.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/netty-resolver-4.1.52.Final.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-6.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/gson-2.8.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/guava-29.0-jre.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.65.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/javax.activation-1.2.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-api-6.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-jps-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/apkzlib-4.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/apksig-4.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/android-jps-model.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/build-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.sdk-common-27.0.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.common-27.0.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.repository-27.0.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.sdklib-27.0.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.layoutlib-api-27.0.0.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/studio.android.sdktools.manifest-merger-27.0.0.0.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 49830 2a37ca47-2a2c-431c-8791-08f781e80ccf /Users/gusiwanaga/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server
Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20CE.app/Contents/lib/util.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0x00000001197a2168, pid=2466, tid=32259
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (15.0.2+7) (build 15.0.2+7-27)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# j  com.sun.tools.javac.comp.ConstFold.fold2(ILcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;+877 jdk.compiler@15.0.2
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/gusiwanaga/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.3/compile-server/hs_err_pid2466.log
Compiled method (c1)   22969  171       1       java.lang.Integer::intValue (5 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x0000000121263490,0x0000000121263700] = 624
 relocation     [0x00000001212635e8,0x0000000121263608] = 32
 main code      [0x0000000121263620,0x00000001212636a0] = 128
 stub code      [0x00000001212636a0,0x00000001212636d0] = 48
 scopes data    [0x00000001212636d0,0x00000001212636d8] = 8
 scopes pcs     [0x00000001212636d8,0x00000001212636f8] = 32
 dependencies   [0x00000001212636f8,0x0000000121263700] = 8
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

PS -> I'm using IntelliJ 2020.3.2 (Community), Oracle openjdk 15.0.2, Macbook Pro M1 (not sure whether this could be related but just in case).

What can I do?

[image]

Update 18/02 23:47: After a few hours and with the support from Andrey, I managed to find the issue: an architecture issue (check [this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788005/java-jdk-for-apple-m1-chip/64788161#64788161/) article fore more info).

Final solution: downloaded JDK from Zulu (apparently, the only one compatible with M1 chips thus far) [here](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a JDK bug. See the same problem in this thread: [mac m1 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65274314/2000323)

I think it is worth reporting to https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

As a workaround try using a different [JDK for the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#set-up-jdk).

Comment: Thank you for the hints. In fact, I did try multiple JDKs and nothing worked.

I've just submitted a ticket to Oracle.

Comment: I had a look at the articles you shared and it was indeed an architecture issue. I'm now using the Zulu OpenJDK and it's working fine. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded JDK from Zulu (apparently, the only one compatible with M1 chips thus far)...
I downloaded it on mac m1
the setting for project Command + ;
Click on download JDK from Zulu.
Apply the changes and try to build it.