# Value of System.getProperty("os.arch") on M1 Mac?

Tags: java, macos, apple-m1

What value does `System.getProperty("os.arch")` return on an AppleSilicon/M1 Mac running the *aarch64* port of the JDK (for example the [Liberica](https://bell-sw.com) port), i.e. **not** using Rosetta2?

Based on [this](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/2200/files#diff-1f93205c2e57bee432f8fb7a0725ba1dfdbe5b901ac63010ea0b43922e34ac12), I am guessing it's `aarch64`. Can anyone confirm this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is, indeed, `aarch64`. At least it is from Azul Zulu Java 11.