# Homebrew can't find openjdk on Macbook pro m1

Tags: java, homebrew, apple-m1, homebrew-cask

I wanted to install openjdk on my new MacBook Pro M1 with Big Sur. I installed Xcode, and homebrew, but if I try to do

```
brew search java
```

I get

```
==> Casks
charles-applejava               java-beta                       java6                           homebrew/cask/eclipse-java
```

and if I do

```
brew search openjdk
```

I get

```
==> Casks
adoptopenjdk8                              microsoft-openjdk11                        homebrew/cask/microsoft-openjdk
```

I know other people have successfully installed openjdk using brew on M1 machines, so I'm wondering what I'm missing here??

Comment: Which version are you hoping to install if 8 and 11 are not acceptable? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64788005/2541560) for non-brew.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my homebrew-core was not at the master branch.  Fixed it with brew doctor and now I can see the openjdk.