# When trying to build "./gradlew build" but it says build failed

Tags: java, github, serial-port, apple-m1, gradlew

I want to install COM port to connect my "Extended" controller (stabilization solution) but the software when plugged in, doesn't show any COM 3 ports. Found this solution https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial

My steps: using the command git clone, after it is downloaded, I changed the directory to the folder it created.
$ cd nrjavaserial

After that, I tried to use this command.
$./gradlew build      But it failed. Leaving this messagge in terminal :

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

> Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache [in thread "Daemon worker"]

Any ideas? My guess is that java is not installed correctly or something is missing. Or support for this is not there.. Thank you in advance.

Using JAVA JDK jdk-18.0.2.1.jdk
M1 Macbook Air.

Comment: Hi, have you tried to execute the command as superuser?

Comment: Hi! Tried it right now, at first it started the download, and then the same problem occurred

Comment: My second guess would be that this is a problem with the M1 of the Macbook but I develope on Windows so this is not my expertiese. Since the M1 is an ARM architecture it could be that you need a special version of the JDK but I don't know

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788005/java-jdk-for-the-apple-m1-chip question can help you here

Comment: After looking at the open Issues of the GitHub page it seems this is in developement right now. See https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial/issues/195