# Why am I getting this error (Error running '__rvm_make -j12') when installing RVM?

Tags: ruby, macos, cmake, rvm

When running the install script for [Ruby Version Manager](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) I keep getting this error:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j12',
please read /Users/wikipediabrown/.rvm/log/1701736892_ruby-3.0.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The logs are cryptic as heck and don't tell me anything.

The end of the log is as follows:

```
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.1'
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
In file included from ossl_x509revoked.c:10:
In file included from ./ossl.h:171:
./openssl_missing.h:195:11: warning: 'TS_VERIFY_CTS_set_certs' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#  define TS_VERIFY_CTS_set_certs(ctx, crts) ((ctx)->certs=(crts))
          ^
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@3/3.2.0/include/openssl/ts.h:426:11: note: previous definition is here
#  define TS_VERIFY_CTS_set_certs(ctx, cert) TS_VERIFY_CTX_set_certs(ctx,cert)
          ^
1 warning generated.
1 warning generated.
linking shared-object ripper.bundle
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lruby.3.1'
7 warnings generated.
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it is a problem with having Java messed up on your machine. For some context the `j12` could be `j*` meaning j anything (`j10`, `j11`, `j12` etc.). That just telling you that your Java installation is messed up and nobody wants to tell you. If you're running anything later than `Mac OS X 10.6` you're gonna find that you need to install it yourself. It's hard to remember that when you've been on the same machine since the slave ships. But I've got a solution for you.

Check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64788005/java-jdk-for-the-apple-silicon-chips)

If you just run:

`brew install openjdk`

**and definitely not:**

`brew install java`

**Ayo, for real!!! don't run that stuff player**

and as per the `Caveats` section it's as easy as pie to miss, you should run this:

```
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk
```

you'll be alright after that. This is just a failure of correct error messaging. Go on and live a good life after this y'all.

Comment: Your current directory is most likely unrelated to any compilation errors. Please edit your question to include the contents of the mentioned file to find the *actual* root cause.

Comment: You was right. I still hate Java and I'm gonna find a way to take some revenge on it in the future.