# Expo-Router Template throwing error when running npm run Android

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, android-emulator

I've just created an Expo Project with the following command:

`npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@50`

I have everything I need installed (I think?): Android Studio, Xcode, etc.
When running npm start android, the emulator opens and then crashes with this error:

```
 ERROR  Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'NativeUnimoduleProxy': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerScreenCaptureObserver from pid=2093, uid=10182 requires android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop 'NativeUnimoduleProxy': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: registerScreenCaptureObserver from pid=2093, uid=10182 requires android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

I have not modified anything in the project. What does this error mean?

I tried just creating the project with the template (from expo docs).
Expected the app to open in Android Emulator, but it crashes.

Comment: Just tried to install expo recently to start a new app, and I'm running into this as well. All my searches lead to suggestions that don't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you´re experiencing this error with `expo go`, your emulator Android System Image is probably "too new". For me "VanillaIceCream" API level wasn't working. Others reported on the expo discord, that "UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox" wasn't working either. I took "UpsideDownCake" / API Level 34 which worked for me. According to official [expo docs](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/android-studio-emulator/) "Tiramisu" also works. I did not try "TiramisuPrivacySandbox".
Here is a screenshot of Android Studio Device Manager [image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working after a few steps.  I'm not sure if these are all necessary, and I'm not sure if this includes everything I did since I tried many things before getting it to work, but hopefully this at least helps.

1. Add the missing permission to the projects: `app.json` file.

   ```json
   {
     "expo": {
       "android": {
         "permissions": [
           "android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE"
         ]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Update the version of expo being used: `yarn expo upgrade`
3. Ensure xcode is set up properly to [prevent issues with glog](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1194#issuecomment-699544467): `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app`
4. Install JDK if you don't already have it installed.  I opted to use OpenJDK, which can be downloaded [here](https://jdk.java.net/21/).  If you're using macOS with an Apple M1 chip, you can follow [these directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66891978).  Ensure that the path to these binaries is added to your `PATH` variable (i.e.: update your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file).
5. Try prebuilding: `yarn expo prebuild`
6. Run your project in Android VM: `yarn android`

Comment: You should add an `npx expo install --fix` step in there