# Config Jenkins slave using Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-kubernetes

I'm trying to setup Jenkins slave using Kubernetes using [kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes). My goal is to have the plugin spin up a GKE container each time there is a job need to run.

I have done the below setup:

1 - create new cluster

2 - create service account with admin role for the cluster

3 - config `jenkins kubernetes` plugin (able to connect to GKE cluster)

4 - config `pod template` (using my custom Docker image which is already pushed to DockerHub)

When I build a project I can see the job running halfway until get to the point below:

```
Agent went offline during the build
ERROR: Connection was broken: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

What is this error and how can I fix it? Is there any other setup needed?

Updated: after searching, I updated my `Dockerfile`. Seems like the container can write already:

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent
USER root

# Install Build Essentials
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get dist-upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install build-essential -y
# Set Environment Variables
ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/home/jenkins/android-sdk" \
    ANDROID_VERSION=30 \
    BUILDTOOL_VERSION="30.0.2" \
    NDK_VERSION="22.0.7026061"

USER jenkins

# Download Android SDK
RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true \
    && echo "24333f8a63b6825ea9c5514f83c2829b004d1fee" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license" \
    && yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses

# Install Android Build Tool and Libraries
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
RUN $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;${BUILDTOOL_VERSION}" \
    "platforms;android-${ANDROID_VERSION}" \
    "platform-tools" \
    "ndk;${NDK_VERSION}"
```

I can see the `Workload` created and build running but don't see why it always stop at the middle with the error above. It seems my pod is disconnected before build finish.

Comment: Could you share your pod template ? Please also run `id` command in the container created from your custom docker image ? What's the result ?

Comment: hi i have updated the question. my container is created dynamically using gke (when there is a job, a new container is created) (can see different name in workload menu)

Comment: ok, actually I wanted to point out that you may need to configure `securityContext` but I see you've already done it. Did you try first to run this custom image locally on plain docker ?

Comment: i updated my `Dockerfile` and can run the container but seem it always stop before completing the build. Updated my question

Comment: ok, so it seems like the initial problem with writing permissions has been solved by escalating privileges using `securityContext`. Unfortunatelly I'm not able to tell you what to do next as it seems like the problem with the imige itself. As far as I understand you, you observe the same behaviour also when you run container from this image on plain docker locally? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45538297/11714114) updating Java from 7 to 8 may help to resolve this issue. Especially _"Check the java version being used by your master, and the java version of your slave."_

Comment: Apart from updating Java on **master** and **slave**, it may be also related with lack of the resources, allocated for your pods. Take a look at the solution presented [here](https://medium.com/@garunski/closedchannelexception-in-jenkins-with-kubernetes-plugin-a7788f1c62a9).