# jenkins agent restart automatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have noticed that jenkins agent which is restarts autometically, and it is very frequently.

```
Connection was broken: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:142)
        at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:792)
        at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
        at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

please help me to fix this.. :-(

Comment: can you please update, this is a windows agent or Linux agent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins Windows slave connection getting terminated with java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433225/jenkins-windows-slave-connection-getting-terminated-with-java-nio-channels-close)

Comment: try to connect your agent , by running agent.jar file via cmd and check the logs under remoting folder if possible post log file here for better understanding