# Jenkins Remote api error Dashboard Logging ID

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm a beginner in Jenkins.
I'm trying to help my boss with the issue below
The Jenkins version is: Jenkins 2.332.2.

> ```
> A problem occurred while processing the request. Logging ID=7aab0cca-a721-4d34-b319-2ea90bd6b005 in the Dashboard Page.
> ```

ERROR LOG in a spoiler below
May 06, 2022 8:36:50 AM WARNING hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression evaluate
Caught exception evaluating: h.printLogRecordHtml(logRecord, prior) in /log/all. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.Functions.printLogRecordHtml(Functions.java:562)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:76)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$3.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:134)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:99)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:66)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:55)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:56)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:43)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Facet$1.dispatch(Facet.java:240)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:224)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:248)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:81)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:60)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

May 06, 2022 8:36:50 AM WARNING hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression evaluate
Caught exception evaluating: h.printLogRecordHtml(logRecord, prior) in /log/all. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.Functions.printLogRecordHtml(Functions.java:562)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:258)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:104)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:76)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$3.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:134)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:101)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:122)
at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:99)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:66)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:55)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:56)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:43)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Facet$1.dispatch(Facet.java:240)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:224)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:248)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:81)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:60)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

If anyone can help I would be grateful.

Comment: This error message does not give enough information to what the error is or what you were doing when the error occurred. More details are required, such as when this issue arises, and any logs that may point to the error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm edited and add the log error but is so big error.

Comment: i'm follow this steps and its working now.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433225/jenkins-windows-slave-connection-getting-terminated-with-java-nio-channels-close